# A fundamental question on multiple rotation of a qubit using $SU(2)$

Tags: qiskit, bloch-sphere, experimental-realization

I am trying to implement qubit rotations using $SU(2)$ from scratch in order to understand and debug what happens under the (physical) hood. The reason why gates and high-level APIs are omitted here is the desired learning effect and the physical understanding of what actually happens beneath the cap.

Implementing the rotation matrix as describes in this [lecture notes](https://www.phys.hawaii.edu/%7Eyepez/Spring2013/lectures/Lecture1_Qubits_Notes.pdf) (equation 25) works fine if I perform one rotation as follows:

```
from qiskit.visualization.bloch import Bloch
from sympy.physics.matrices import msigma
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy import N, re
import numpy as np

def to_spherical(vec):
    x = np.real(vec[0])
    y = np.real(vec[1])
    z = np.real(vec[2])
    hxy = np.hypot(x, y)
    r = np.hypot(hxy, z)
    ϕ = np.arctan2(y, x) #az
    θ = np.arctan2(z, hxy) #el
    return [r, ϕ, θ]

def to_cartesian(polar):
    r = polar[0]
    ϕ = polar[1]
    θ = polar[2]
    x = r * np.sin(ϕ) * np.cos(θ)
    y = r * np.sin(ϕ) * np.sin(θ)
    z = r * np.cos(ϕ)
    return [np.real(x), np.real(y), np.real(z)]

def rn_su2(vec, rot_angle, n):
    spherical_vec = to_spherical(vec)
    ϕ = spherical_vec[1]
    θ = spherical_vec[2]
    
    sx = msigma(1)
    sy = msigma(2)
    sz = msigma(3)
    M_q = (np.sin(θ)*np.cos(ϕ)*sx + np.sin(θ)*np.sin(ϕ)*sy + np.cos(θ)*sz)
    U_n = np.eye(2)*np.cos(rot_angle/2) -1j*(n[0]*sx+n[1]*sy+n[2]*sz)*np.sin(rot_angle/2)
    M_q_rotated = U_n*M_q*np.matrix(U_n).H
    return M_q_rotated

def extract_angles(M_q_rotated):
    cos_θ_rotated = float(N(re(M_q_rotated[0,0])))
    θ_rotated = np.arccos(cos_θ_rotated)
    
    # e^(ix) = cos(x) + i*sin(x)
    # see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity
    temp = float(N(re(M_q_rotated[1,0])))
    temp = temp/np.sin(θ_rotated)
    ϕ_rotated = np.arccos(temp)
    return (ϕ_rotated, θ_rotated)
```

After having implemented the fundamental functions, the most interesting part is to perform the rotations of a Qubit. In the following I am trying to take a vector, rotate it by $\frac{\pi}{8}$ around the $z$-axis, then in the next step I take the resulting rotated vector and rotate it again by $\frac{\pi}{8}$ around the $z$-axis and so forth:

```
rot_angle = np.pi/8
n = [0, 0, 1]

start_vec = [1, 0, 0]

num_iterations = 5
_bloch = Bloch()
_bloch.vector_color = ['blue'] * num_iterations

sv = []
vec = start_vec
sv.append(vec)
for i in range(num_iterations):
    M_q_rotated = rn_su2(vec, rot_angle, n)
    (ϕ_rotated, θ_rotated) = extract_angles(M_q_rotated)
    vec = np.array(to_cartesian([1, ϕ_rotated, θ_rotated]))
    sv.append(vec)

_bloch.add_vectors(sv)
_bloch.render()
```

I am using qiskit for visualizing the vectors on a blochsphere. The first rotation works really well, but the subsequent ones not:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help to get the subsequent rotations working. The complete notebook is publicly available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/bloch_sphere/rotate_su2_qiskit_eldar-sultanow.ipynb).

***Update (2022-06-13):***
After fixing the issues enlisted in the great answer of Egretta.Thula, the plot looks as follows (see updated code [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/bloch_sphere/rotate_su2_qiskit_eldar-sultanow.ipynb)):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one issue in your code.

1. You switched `ϕ` and `θ` in the function that convert polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates:

```
    x = r * np.sin(ϕ) * np.cos(θ)
    y = r * np.sin(ϕ) * np.sin(θ)
    z = r * np.cos(ϕ)
```

2. `hxy` and `z` are passed in a wrong order while calculating `θ` in `to_spherical` function:

```
    θ = np.arctan2(z, hxy)
```

3. SymPy uses `I` instead of `j` for imaginary numbers. That makes `numpy.matrix.H` not working properly. You should use [`Dagger`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/quantum/dagger.html) instead.

**Update:**

There is another issue in the code which takes place when `num_iterations` $\geq 8$,

`extract_angles` uses real part of $e^{i\phi}$ to calculate the value of $\phi$. You should take both real and imaginary parts. Otherwise you will always get a value between $0$ and $\pi$. So you will need to change these lines of code:

```
    temp = float(N(re(M_q_rotated[1,0])))
    temp = temp/np.sin(θ_rotated)
    ϕ_rotated = np.arccos(temp)
```

to become:

```
    temp = M_q_rotated[1,0]/np.sin(θ_rotated)
    temp_r = float(N(re(temp)))
    temp_i = float(N(im(temp)))
    ϕ_rotated = np.arctan2(temp_i, temp_r)
```

I think this is the root cause of the issue described [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27015/9474).

Comment: Your answer is great and works. I updated my OP and added the new plot resulting from your fixes. I pushed the updated code to [GitHub](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/bloch_sphere/rotate_su2_qiskit_eldar-sultanow.ipynb). Thank you again.